# Why am I getting, "Invalid assignment on left-hand side"?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie to track visits.

```
if (getCookie(pageCount) == "") {
    var pageCount = 1;
} else {
    parseInt (pageCount)++;
}
setCookie(pageCount, pageCount, expire);
```

The above code gives me the error "Invalid assignment on left-hand side" around `parseInt` though.  Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Try assigning it to something before adding to it? `pageCount = parseInt(pageCount) + 1;`

Comment: That fixed the problem, but for some reason it still returns NaN?

Comment: So you're using `pageCount` to store the cookie name and value?

Comment: That is correct. Could they be conflicting when I parse?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (getCookie(pageCount) == "") { 
    var pageCount = 1; 
} else { 
    var pageCount = parseInt (pageCount || 0);
    pageCount ++; 
} 
setCookie(pageCount, pageCount, expire);
```

Comment: That rectified the firebug error, but now im receiving NaN when I try and write it to the page?

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt(pageCount)++;
```

What do you expect that increment operation to do?

Comment: @Cluckles: But it's attempting to increment the result of `parseInt`, not `pageCount`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
if ( getCookie(pageCount) ) { 
    var pageCount = 1; 
} else { 
    var pageCount = (+pageCount || 0) + 1;
} 
setCookie(pageCount, pageCount, expire);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getCookie("pageCount") == "") {
    var pageCount = 1;
} else {
    var pageCount = parseInt(getCookie("pageCount"));
    pageCount++;
}
setCookie("pageCount", pageCount, expire);
```